# What's the best way to download a php generated file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using a jquery $.post request to generate a gpx file. The post request then returns the unique id the file has been saved with. Now I would like to download this file, but change te name of the file from the unique id to a name that a user has specified in an input div.

I've been researching and it seems that this is not possible using another post request to send the name data.

I can't use location.href because the file name needs to change and I need to send that new name with the download request.

How can I solve this?

Comment: why not send the name in the initial post request and create the file with the proper name to begin with?

Comment: because I wanted to prevent files overwriting accidently when creating alot of different ones with different users. guess I'm just gonna be creating a unique folder for the file and name it right the first time :) thanks

Comment: you could do that, make a folder for each user etc. Another option, and my prefered method is to append a timestamp to the end of the filename.

Comment: The timestamp is a great idea, didn't think of that. thanks!

Comment: Might be a weird question (as I don't know your project and you've given little information), but, why do you not respond with the file instead of filename? Use @LSerni's answer and straight away return the file to the client instead of an ID which triggers a request to get the file? You can change the name of the file to whatever you wish before you return it to the client. Also, use `$.post` to send data to the server (and get a response), and `$.get` to request data from the server (as a response). Of course you could use `$.ajax` and specify the type in the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use location.href because the file name needs to change and I need to send that new name with the download request.

Yes, you can.

Simply do not send the **file name** location, but the location of a PHP script which will retrieve the *correct* file, whatever its name (e.g. a unique), then retrieve the correct local name (e.g. from a $_SESSION), and send the appropriate headers:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf;charset=UTF-8');
header('COntent-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyStrangeName.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($realFile));
readfile($realFile);
```

This also allows you to establish, via $_SESSION, that the downloader really has the right to download the file.

For very large file quantities I suggest you adopt a uniquename plus file tree solution, à la Squid, e.g.

```
uniqueid = 4fd3ea17 // Unique file ID
file     = downloads/4f/d3/4fd3ea17
```

So each directory only contains at most 65536 files.

Then with a little help from mod-rewrite you can send

```
Location: http://www.yoursite.com/download/4fd3ea17
```

(Do not forget to deny direct access and index to the downloads directory)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the php rename() function. With another post request you can pass the unique name and the name the user has choosen. You rename the file and send it's name as a response. Then with jQuery you can do whatever you want with the response. So it's:

1. Send to the php script with the rename() function the unique name, and the new name
2. Make the script rename the file, and send the new name as $.post response
3. Use jQuery to do whatever you want with the response.

Comment: Yes it makes sense but I don't know if he wants to upload it with an unique id and then change the file's name. He asked how to rename it and I told him how to. Something that would make sense if he really wanted an unique id would be creating a directory with an unique id and store the correctly named file inside there.

Comment: Fair enough, but your method would in fact rename the file giving the exact same result as naming it correctly in the first place. Now, if your method produced a *copy* of the file with something like `copy($file, $newfile)`, it would make a bit more sense (leaving the original file under the unique id to be used again later perhaps)